# Error 'libudunits2.a not found' when installing ggraph, Additional Error : object ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'

Tags: apt, 17.10, libraries, r, rstudio

I ran into these two errors
`'libudunits2.a not found'` and `Error : object ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'`
on Ubuntu 17.10 during an install of ggraph in Rstudio via 
`install.packages("ggraph")`. 
I tried to find a solution online but it seems that a lot of people are having the same problem. I suspect this is similar in other versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first error `'libudunits2.a not found'`
 by installing libudunits2 at command line :

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev
```

I next got a new error when I returned to Rstudio: 
`Error : object ‘scale_type’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'`

I came across an old post from [github](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/ggtree/issues/16) which worked for me. Install in Rstudio with:

```
devtools::install_github(c("hadley/ggplot2", "GuangchuangYu/ggtree"))
```

with the following command to install ggraph in Rstudio:

```
install.packages("ggraph")
```